# Specifications for functions: -spec. Efficiently usage

Tags: erlang

How could I use `-spec` word in erlang?
Please give me an idea of efficient usage of this word. Does is stands for documentation purposes only?

I'm try to apply a constraint to function in module by function type specification using `-spec`, but I've failed - no restrictions have been applied.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`-spec` attributes are indeed treated by the compiler and the runtime system as documentation. You cannot add any "executable features" to your code using them and the same applies for `-type` and `-opaque` attributes.

However they are useful as:

- **Documentation**: they used by EDoc to generate all different forms of documentation for your code. `-spec` attributes are function signatures which, depending on how much effort you put into them, can make your code more understandable and maintainable. Suppose that your favorite data structure this month is `dict()`. Consider the following code:

  ```
  my_function(SomeArg, SomeOtherArg, Dict) ->
    ...
    dict:find(SomeKey, Dict)
    ...
  ```

  The variable that is being used as a dict has been named as such. But let's say that you have the following snippet:

  ```
  my_other_function(NamesDict, PlacesDict) ->
    ...
    R1 = my_function(A, B, NamesDict),
    ...
    R2 = my_function(C, D, PlacesDict),
  ...
  ```

  Trying to keep up with this might soon lead to code that repeats this `Dict` suffix. Even more, you might not even want to remember in the context of `my_other_function` that the two arguments are `dict()`. So instead you might want to do this:

  ```
  -spec my_other_function(dict(), dict()) -> atom().

  my_other_function(Names, Places) ->
    ...
    R1 = my_function(A, B, Names),
    ...
    R2 = my_function(C, D, Places),
    ...
  ```

  Now it is clear that these arguments should be dict() for the function to work and hopefully everyone will be able to figure that without going deep into the code. But suppose you are using this `Name` `dict()` in other places and it stores some particular information that is exposed with different APIs. Then it's a perfect candidate for a `-type` declaration:

  ```
  -type names() :: dict().

  -spec my_other_function(names(), places()) -> atom().

  my_other_function(Names, Places) ->
    ...
    R1 = my_function(A, B, Names),
    ...
    R2 = my_function(C, D, Places),
    ...
  ```

  If somebody else makes frequent use of this particular data structure you may want to export it too:

  ```
  -module(my_module).

  -export_type([names/0]).

  -type names() :: dict().
  ```

  Other modules can now refer to this particular data structure:

  ```
  -module(my_other_module).

  -record(my_state, {names :: my_module:names(),
                     ...}).
  ```

  Finally if you would prefer other developer to not inspect this data structure in any way in their modules, you can declare it as `-opaque`. Again, this is a "friendly suggestion", as is all the rest of the stuff so far. Or is it...?
- **Discrepancy detection**: If you take time to use `-specs` and `-types` you would very much like that these are kept up to date. It is common knowledge that nobody maintains the documentation up to date if there is none watching! Luckily, **Dialyzer** is watching. Dialyzer **can** [check](https://www.erlang-factory.com/conference/ErlangUserConference2011/speakers/StavrosAronis) that in all calls to `my_function()` the arguments are `dict()` (it can do this even without your `-spec` annotations but it's so easier if there are these there too) and scream bloody murder if you call it with something else. It can moreover keep track of these exported types and even report opacity violations. So it's not "just documentation".
- **Testcase generation**: **PropEr** can use the `-spec` and `-type` definitions to automatically check your functions with random testcases. It is capable to make random testcases even from declarations like this one:

  ```
  -type int_tree() :: {node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil.
  ```
- The brand new way to specify a set of **callbacks** for a behaviour is by using the familiar `-spec` syntax. Compiler, Dialyzer and possibly other tools can use this information to check a behaviours implementation. See more in the OTP behaviours [code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl) and [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72728)

Read more [here](http://www.erlang-factory.com/conference/SFBay2011/speakers/KostisSagonas).

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Is the `-opaque` means the same as `-type` without `-export_type` declaration?

Comment: No, you still need to export any `-opaque` types you declare.

Answer (score 9):

`-spec`'s for functions are specifications which has several places where they help:

- They act as documentation of the function. Generating EDoc will pull the specs and make them available in the documentation.
- They are a specification for the dialyzer. When the dialyzer runs it will use the specs to determine if the code is wrong in any way. That is, if you spec is wrong - and in some cases it will help the system to understand exactly why the code is wrong too.
- They are a valuable tool in the specification of behaviours. There is a new `-callback` keyword which can be used to do this for behavioural APIs.
- They are valuable for constructing a type skeleton of how the program fits together and from where data comes from.
- Together with the cousins `-type` and `-opaque` you can force certain types to be opaque to pieces of code. That means you are not allowed to see the internal representation on a static verification level. This can in turn help drive modularized code as you are not allowed to tightly couple code pieces.

Comment: Thank you, but help me with the last one statement please. What is the difference between `-type` and `-opaque`. We could use `-type` into the one module only, and if we want it to become visible, we must provide `-export_type` word. Is this the same terms `-type` and `-opaque` if we don't use `-export_type` word?

Comment: Can you please point to some docs about this new `-callback` keyword?

Comment: Ivan, see http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72728 for example. I have a lot of fun looking through all erlang docs to find one thing or another. It seems Erlang guys write all valuable docs at the end of almost all documents - mans, system principles, referencese. So if you want to start writing and understandind erlang programs you should read docs from bottom up to top )

Comment: N.B. dilyzer does not **need** specs, as it always works out the types of a functions arguments and return value anyway. If there are specs it checks them against the "real" specs and warns if they are inconsistent.